# Keyboard shortcuts for Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, keyboard

I am new to SFMC.

Are there any keyboard shortcuts to navigate around Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

I've Googled but couldn't find anything.

I would like to do things like switch to the next Subscriber preview without having to click  the arrow button each time.

Comment: There aren't any, as far as I know.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs Thanks for your reply Adam. I am surprised at this: I can't be the only SFMC user who would find keyboard shortcuts extremely useful? Has this feature been requested before?